# Structuring a table using Scrapy Data

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a website that contains tables (trs and tds).  I want to create a structured CSV file from the table data.  I'm trying to create field names from the scraped table as those field names can change depending upon the month or selections.

While I have been successful at iterating through the table and actually scraping the data I want to use as my field names I have yet to figure out how to yield that data into the CSV file.

Right now I have them scraped into an Item named "h1header" and when yielded to a CSV file they appear as rows under that item key "h1header" so:

```
Project Owning Org
Project Date Range
Fee Factor
Project Organization
Project Manager
Fee Calculation Method
Project Code
Project Lead
Status
Project Title
Total Project Value
Condition
External System Code
Funded Value
Billing Type
```

What I would ultimately like is the following:

```
Project Owning Org, Project Date Range, Fee Factor, Project Organization ...etc
```

so instead of rows they are columns and then I can populate the multiple tables on the page that are formatted with the same h1header with the data as field values of those columns.
Below is an example of the html that I'm scraping.  This particular tbody.h1 repeats multiple times on the page depending on the results.

```
<table class="report">
<tbody class="h1"><tr><td colspan="22">
<table class="report" >
<tbody class="h1">
<tr>
<td class="label">Project Owning Organization:</td><td>1.02.10</td>
<td class="label">Project Date Range:</td><td>8/12/2020 - 8/11/2021</td>
<td class="label">Fee Factor:</td><td>&#8212;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label">Project Organization:</td><td>1.2.26.1</td>
<td class="label">Project Manager:</td><td>Smith, John</td>
<td class="label">Fee Calculation Method:</td><td>&#8212;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label">Project Code:</td><td>PROJECT.001</td>
<td class="label">Project Lead:</td><td>Doe, Jane</td>
<td class="label">Status:</td><td>Backlog</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label">Project Title:</td><td>Scrapy Project</td>
<td class="label">Total Project Value:</td><td>1,438.00</td>
<td class="label">Condition:</td><td>Green<img src="/images/status_green.png" alt="Green" 
title="Green"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label">External System Code:</td><td>&#8212;</td>
<td class="label">Funded Value:</td><td>1,438.00</td>
<td class="label">Billing Type:</td><td>FP</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

There are other tables within this html (tbody.h1 and tbody.detail) where I will then need to append columns to the above.

I've done this in Java using Beautiful Soup by creating and writing to arrays then ultimately exporting those built arrays as csv files.  Python Scrapy is FAR easier to get the data than Java was and I'm sure I'm over complicating this but am stuck trying to figure it out so any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, req, utils

html = '''
    <table class="report">
    <tbody class="h1"><tr><td colspan="22">
    <table class="report" >
    <tbody class="h1">
    <tr>
    <td class="label">Project Owning Organization:</td><td>1.02.10</td>
    <td class="label">Project Date Range:</td><td>8/12/2020 - 8/11/2021</td>
    <td class="label">Fee Factor:</td><td>&#8212;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="label">Project Organization:</td><td>1.2.26.1</td>
    <td class="label">Project Manager:</td><td>Smith, John</td>
    <td class="label">Fee Calculation Method:</td><td>&#8212;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="label">Project Code:</td><td>PROJECT.001</td>
    <td class="label">Project Lead:</td><td>Doe, Jane</td>
    <td class="label">Status:</td><td>Backlog</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="label">Project Title:</td><td>Scrapy Project</td>
    <td class="label">Total Project Value:</td><td>1,438.00</td>
    <td class="label">Condition:</td><td>Green<img src="/images/status_green.png" alt="Green" 
    title="Green"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="label">External System Code:</td><td>&#8212;</td>
    <td class="label">Funded Value:</td><td>1,438.00</td>
    <td class="label">Billing Type:</td><td>FP</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </tbody>
</table>
'''
# html = req.get('your url') 
# html = utils.getFileContent('your file path')

# header = []
rows = []
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
tds = doc.selects('table.report>table.report>td')
row = []
for i in range(0,len(tds),2):
    # header.append(tds[i].text.strip(':'))
    row.append(tds[i+1].text)

# rows.append(header)
rows.append(row)

utils.save2csv('test.csv', rows, mode='a')
```

Comment: Thank you!  Closer, but it appears that if I run this on the headers the save2csv util is creating a column for every letter of the header label and then creating a new row and doing the same to the next label.  So basically P,r,o,j,ec,t,,O,r,g,a,n...  Also I'm using scrapy-splash AND it's behind a login because this is all JS generated html and using the req.get just gets me the login page.  That is just another problem to solve ;)

Answer (score 0):

dabingsou, thank you for the inspiration.  While your solution didn't work for my code your idea to use a csv utility other than what was bundled with Scrapy was the solution I was looking for!

My code was very similar to what you wrote with the exception of your MUCH more simplistic way of only looping once through the headers!  Below is my code that I utilized and then simply added the csv package to write the file perfectly!  This code utilizes Scrapy vs simple-scrapy and allows me to scrape the page using scrapy-splash.

```
def h1header_scrape(self, response):
    td_labels = response.css('tbody.h1 td.label')
    h1headers = []
    lastitemnum = len(td_labels)-1 #This provides the last item number and subtracts the duplicate "Project Organization" label in the first tr in the css
    lastheader= response.css('tbody.h1 td.label::text')[lastitemnum].get() #Using the count function defined above this gets the last header name in h1 and uses it to stop the for loop below
    for td_label in td_labels:
        columns = td_label.css('td.label')
        header = columns.css('.label::text').get()
        h1header = columns.css('.label::text').get().replace(":","")
        h1headers.append(h1header)
        if header == lastheader:
            break
    print(h1headers)
    with open('testfile.csv','w',newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(h1headers)
```

Comment: congratulations!